# Texturing help for elevator interior

Tags: texturing

[image]I'm extremely new to Blender. Just learned the basics over the weekend. Texturing is easily one of the aspects I'm worst at. I need some help making a texture for the inside of an elevator. The metal in elevators always has that unique reflective vertical strips look. I have no idea how to replicate it in Blender.[image]

Comment: Sorry if you saw my post earlier. The text editor didn't save my finished draft, so when I submitted it, it had deleted the entire question

Comment: Could you edit to provide some example images? You might be better off without a texture for a lot of it and just a fancy material (for smooth shiny surfaces). Materials let you do a LOT of cool stuff with or without use of textures, you could probably find some good examples of what you're after online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is a brushed metal you should use an *Anisotropic* node. It is a *Glossy* node but it stretches the reflection on a certain axis (Z by default but you can plug an *Input* > *Tangent* node in the *Tangent* socket if necessary). Also plug a b&w texture to give it apparent vertical lines.

[image]